# I want to change the display depending on the value of the select box of woocommerce_form_field in WooCommerce

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce on WordPress.
I'm trying to add a new user information item on the edit-account page.
I added an item using a function called woocommerce_form_field. (The code below)
I also used woocommerce_form_field (type => text) under that item to add some items.
So I want to display additional items after that depending on the value of selectbox.
However, it has not been implemented.
I changed the select box, but I couldn't get the value.
How can I achieve this by using jquery (". ClassName"). change (function () ...?
I am asking a question using the translation function. I'm sorry if the English is not good.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'misha_add_field_edit_account_form' );
function misha_add_field_edit_account_form() {
woocommerce_form_field(
        'XX',
        array(
            'type'        => 'select',
            'required'    => false, 
            'label'       => 'OO',
            'options' => array(
                '' => 'A',
                'b' => 'B',
                'c' => 'C',
            )
        ),
        
        get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'XX', true )
    );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'misha_save_account_details' );
function misha_save_account_details( $user_id ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'XX', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['XX'] ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was made in this way.
It seems that it had to be implemented in JavaScript.

```
jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('select').change(function() {
            var sel_val = jQuery(this).val();
            if (sel_val == "b") {...
```